# How do I make Google show rich snippets in the search results now that I have implemented structured data?

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, search-results, google-rich-snippets-tool, rich-cards

I have written and inserted [Google Search Gallery](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/search-gallery) scripts into our website so that to see article carousels, company logo, info, etc in the search results.

Now when I search specific keywords I don't see that search gallery (or rich cards) changes and improvements. The search results are the same as before.

Is there any way to make Google understand my changes and show them in search results?
Or is there a specific way to see the changes in the search results?

P.S I have found [this tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) only however it is of no help.

Comment: When you say that the structured data testing tool is of no help, do you mean that it is not reporting any errors with your structured data?

Comment: You don't say, however, patience is required. How long have you waited?